# Adding compiled library to CMake Qt Project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, cmake

I have been trying to include the latest version of qextserialport into the project I am working on. The project structure is as below:

- CameraProject

  - CameraProject.pro
  - CameraProject

    - Headers
    - Sources
  - qextserialport

    - Headers
    - Sources

My CMake file currently looks like so:

```
PROJECT(CameraProject)
FIND_PACKAGE(Qt4 REQUIRED)

FIND_LIBRARY(SIMPLONLIB lv.simplon lib)
FIND_LIBRARY(SIMPLONIMGPROC lv.simplon.imgproc lib)

SET(CameraProject_SOURCES include/lv.simplon.class.cpp camera.cpp main.cpp mainwindow.cpp osdep.cpp paint.cpp)
SET(CameraProject_HEADERS include/lv.simplon.class.h camera.h mainwindow.h osdep.h paint.h)
SET(CameraProject_RESOURCES icons.qrc)

INCLUDE(${QT_USE_FILE})
ADD_DEFINITIONS(${QT_DEFINITIONS})

ADD_EXECUTABLE(CameraProject ${CameraProject_SOURCES}
                ${CameraProject_HEADERS_MOC}
                ${CameraProject_RESOURCES_RCC})

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(CameraProject ${QT_LIBRARIES} ${SIMPLONLIB} ${SIMPLONIMGPROC})
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} include QExtSerialPort/src)
```

And despite including the QextSerialPort files in the Include Directories, I get linker issues being drawn.

EDIT: More information!

Found here is the qextserialport.pri file that is included in CameraProject.pro like so: `include(./QExtSerialPort/src/qextserialport.pri)`

Should I be making a second CMakeLists file for the qextserialport library placed within the source folder?

Any input would be greatly appreciated, please do not hesitate to request for clarification or any further information.

Comment: Other than my posted answer you could make a second CMakeLists.txt for qextserialport inside your project if you want to just use this one part of qxt. I have done similar with wwWidgets.

Comment: You most likely want to put the second CMakeLists.txt file in a subfolder probably named qextserialport. And use the add_subdirectory command in your main CMakeLists.txt to pull in the CMakeLists.txt in the subfolder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What did for qxt is to use a cmake finder module instead of directly including the code into my projects. I then built qxt with qmake and let CMake find the libraries it creates.

```
#############
## basic FindQxt.cmake
## This is an *EXTREMELY BASIC* cmake find/config file for
## those times you have a cmake project and wish to use
## libQxt.
##
## It should be noted that at the time of writing, that
## I (mschnee) have an extremely limited understanding of the
## way Find*.cmake files work, but I have attempted to
## emulate what FindQt4.cmake and a few others do.
##
##  To enable a specific component, set your QXT_USE_${modname}:
##  SET(QXT_USE_QXTCORE TRUE)
##  SET(QXT_USE_QXTGUI FALSE)
##  Currently available components:
##  QxtCore, QxtGui, QxtNetwork, QxtWeb, QxtSql
##  Auto-including directories are enabled with INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(), but
##  can be accessed if necessary via ${QXT_INCLUDE_DIRS}
##
## To add the libraries to your build, TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(), such as...
##  TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(YourTargetNameHere ${QXT_LIBRARIES})
## ...or..
##  TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(YourTargetNameHere ${QT_LIBRARIES} ${QXT_LIBRARIES})
################### TODO:
##      The purpose of this cmake file is to find what components
##  exist, regardless of how libQxt was build or configured, thus
##  it should search/find all possible options.  As I am not aware
##  that any module requires anything special to be used, adding all
##  modules to ${QXT_MODULES} below should be sufficient.
##      Eventually, there should be version numbers, but
##  I am still too unfamiliar with cmake to determine how to do
##  version checks and comparisons.
##      At the moment, this cmake returns a failure if you
##  try to use a component that doesn't exist.  I don't know how to
##  set up warnings.
##      It would be nice having a FindQxt.cmake and a UseQxt.cmake
##  file like done for Qt - one to check for everything in advance

##############

###### setup
SET(QXT_MODULES QxtGui QxtWeb QxtZeroConf QxtNetwork QxtSql QxtBerkeley QxtCore)
SET(QXT_FOUND_MODULES)
FOREACH(mod ${QXT_MODULES})
    STRING(TOUPPER ${mod} U_MOD)
    SET(QXT_${U_MOD}_INCLUDE_DIR NOTFOUND)
    SET(QXT_${U_MOD}_LIB_DEBUG NOTFOUND)
    SET(QXT_${U_MOD}_LIB_RELEASE NOTFOUND)
    SET(QXT_FOUND_${U_MOD} FALSE)
ENDFOREACH(mod)
SET(QXT_QXTGUI_DEPENDSON QxtCore)
SET(QXT_QXTWEB_DEPENDSON QxtCore QxtNetwork)
SET(QXT_QXTZEROCONF_DEPENDSON QxtCore QxtNetwork)
SET(QXT_QXTNETWORK_DEPENDSON QxtCore)
SET(QXT_QXTQSQL_DEPENDSON QxtCore)
SET(QXT_QXTBERKELEY_DEPENDSON QxtCore)

FIND_PATH(QXT_DIR libqxt.pro Qxt/include/QxtCore/Qxt)
FIND_PATH(QXT_BINARY_DIR 
    NAMES QxtCore.dll QxtCored.dll 
    PATHS 
    ${QXT_DIR}/bin  
    ${QXT_DIR}/Bin 
    NO_DEFAULT_PATH
)

#SET(QXT_BINARY_DIR "${QXT_DIR}/bin" CACHE PATH "${QXT_DIR}/bin")

FOREACH(mod ${QXT_MODULES})
    STRING(TOUPPER ${mod} U_MOD)
    FIND_PATH(QXT_${U_MOD}_INCLUDE_DIR ${mod}
        PATH_SUFFIXES ${mod} include/${mod} Qxt/include/${mod} include/Qxt/${mod}
        PATHS
        ~/Library/Frameworks/
        /Library/Frameworks/
        /sw/
        /usr/local/
        /usr
        /opt/local/
        /opt/csw
        /opt
        "C:\\"
        "C:\\Program Files\\"
        "C:\\Program Files(x86)\\"
        ${QXT_DIR}
        NO_DEFAULT_PATH
    )
    FIND_LIBRARY(QXT_${U_MOD}_LIB_RELEASE NAME ${mod}
        PATH_SUFFIXES Qxt/lib64 Qxt/lib lib64 lib
        PATHS
        /sw
        /usr/local
        /usr
        /opt/local
        /opt/csw
        /opt
        "C:\\"
        "C:\\Program Files"
        "C:\\Program Files(x86)"
        ${QXT_DIR}
        NO_DEFAULT_PATH
    )
    FIND_LIBRARY(QXT_${U_MOD}_LIB_DEBUG NAME ${mod}d
        PATH_SUFFIXES Qxt/lib64 Qxt/lib lib64 lib
        PATHS
        /sw
        /usr/local
        /usr
        /opt/local
        /opt/csw
        /opt
        "C:\\"
        "C:\\Program Files"
        "C:\\Program Files(x86)"
        ${QXT_DIR}
        NO_DEFAULT_PATH
    )
    IF (QXT_${U_MOD}_LIB_RELEASE)
        SET(QXT_FOUND_MODULES "${QXT_FOUND_MODULES} ${mod}")
    ENDIF (QXT_${U_MOD}_LIB_RELEASE)

    IF (QXT_${U_MOD}_LIB_DEBUG)
        SET(QXT_FOUND_MODULES "${QXT_FOUND_MODULES} ${mod}")
    ENDIF (QXT_${U_MOD}_LIB_DEBUG)
ENDFOREACH(mod)

FOREACH(mod ${QXT_MODULES})
    STRING(TOUPPER ${mod} U_MOD)
    IF(QXT_${U_MOD}_INCLUDE_DIR AND QXT_${U_MOD}_LIB_RELEASE)
        SET(QXT_FOUND_${U_MOD} TRUE)
    ENDIF(QXT_${U_MOD}_INCLUDE_DIR AND QXT_${U_MOD}_LIB_RELEASE)
ENDFOREACH(mod)


##### find and include
# To use a Qxt Library....
#   SET(QXT_FIND_COMPONENTS QxtCore, QxtGui)
# ...and this will do the rest
IF( QXT_FIND_COMPONENTS )
    FOREACH( component ${QXT_FIND_COMPONENTS} )
        STRING( TOUPPER ${component} _COMPONENT )
        SET(QXT_USE_${_COMPONENT}_COMPONENT TRUE)
    ENDFOREACH( component )
ENDIF( QXT_FIND_COMPONENTS )

SET(QXT_LIBRARIES "")
SET(QXT_INCLUDE_DIRS "")

# like FindQt4.cmake, in order of dependence
FOREACH( module ${QXT_MODULES} )
    STRING(TOUPPER ${module} U_MOD)
    IF(QXT_USE_${U_MOD} OR QXT_DEPENDS_${U_MOD})
        IF(QXT_FOUND_${U_MOD})
            STRING(REPLACE "QXT" "" qxt_module_def "${U_MOD}")
            ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DQXT_${qxt_module_def}_LIB)
            SET(QXT_INCLUDE_DIRS ${QXT_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${QXT_${U_MOD}_INCLUDE_DIR})
            INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${QXT_${U_MOD}_INCLUDE_DIR})
            SET(QXT_LIBRARIES ${QXT_LIBRARIES};optimized;${QXT_${U_MOD}_LIB_RELEASE};debug;${QXT_${U_MOD}_LIB_DEBUG})
        ELSE(QXT_FOUND_${U_MOD})
            MESSAGE("Could not find Qxt Module ${module}")
            RETURN()
        ENDIF(QXT_FOUND_${U_MOD})
        FOREACH(dep QXT_${U_MOD}_DEPENDSON)
            SET(QXT_DEPENDS_${dep} TRUE)
        ENDFOREACH(dep)
    ENDIF(QXT_USE_${U_MOD} OR QXT_DEPENDS_${U_MOD})
ENDFOREACH(module)
MESSAGE(STATUS "Found Qxt Libraries:${QXT_FOUND_MODULES}")

MESSAGE(STATUS "Include directories:${QXT_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
```

I put this module in a sub directory of my root project called CMake/Modules and include it into cmake near the top of the root CMakeLists.txt using the following command:

```
    # The following line will add additional finders to CMake without the need to be placed in the CMake install path
    LIST(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/CMake/Modules)
```

And finally to have CMake find Qxt

```
SET(QXT_FIND_COMPONENTS QxtCore, QxtGui)
SET(QXT_USE_QXTCORE TRUE)
FIND_PACKAGE(Qxt REQUIRED)
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for your detailed response, I was giving it a shot over the last thirty minutes, and found our that it is indeed possible to do it in a single CMakeLists file, does this seem like it is doing anything incorrectly? http://pastie.org/4384328

Comment: You do not appear to be using QextSerialPort_SOURCES. Although you can just add that to you ADD_EXECUTABLE command.

Comment: Hey! Thank you so much. It finally did build, however this guy popped up though, http://i.imgur.com/kTmeI.png , any ideas?

Comment: You need to switch your startup project to the .exe and not the library since a library is not executable.